# How did Sapna become super rich, educated and well spoken in 2 years?

Tags: plot-explanation, leila

In the Netflix original "Leila", we see that

**Sapna, the maid of Shalini, is later a very rich housewife and her husband, Mohan is the "right hand" of Joshi, the ruler of Aryavarta**

The time that elapsed between Shalini's capture and her returning to the inner circle as a Category 5 help is 2 years and few months (or weeks)

2 years: Pooja and Shalini have a conversation in episode 1 as to how much time has passed since she came here and Shalini says 2 years

Few months/weeks: Her becoming a Category 5 helper to when she meets Sapna

Sapna says she was already with Mohan (who was a right hand to Joshi even then) when she was a maid of Shalini when the incident happened.

**So my question is how did Sapna become very educated & super eloquent in english (not to mention super rich) in a span of 2 years ? or is my timeline wrong ?**

Answer (score 1):

**How did Sapna become super rich, educated and well spoken in 2 years?**

First, remember our first introduction with Sapna was through Shalini's, memories and
she never asked much about her so we never know how much educated she was. Shalini also being quite educated end up as a panchkarmi. And also speaking Hindi and English doesn't mean highly educated, in south India, you can easily meet a  houseworker who are fluent in English without much education.

Second thing, her husband Mohan was with Joshi long before 2 years, so they have surely more than 2 years to achieve that and have an upper-level Aryavrat person in your pocket you can surely have some ways to get early success.

Comment: OMG I didn't mean to make it sound like that ! All of a sudden she seemed so polished (not just the english , but the way she carried herself and her way of conducting things).. We do hear her speak once to Shalini regarding taking bath (that they don't have water regularly in her place so she couldn't take a bath before coming). I inferred that she isn't of "Shalini's" kind of background, depending on her access to water. During the flashback she didnt seem so.

Comment: " so we never know how much educated she was. Shalini also being quite educated end up as a panchkarmi" this i agree with.

Comment: "her husband Mohan was with Joshi long before 2 years, so they have surely more than 2 years to achieve that and have an upper-level Aryavrat person in your pocket you can surely have some ways to get early success." THIS has me confused. if he had been a right hand of joshi from long back and if these two people were married, why was she a help in the first place ?

Comment: @Anu7 maybe she was panchkarmi before marriage after marriage Mohan started working to fix there condition and it took some time.

Comment: Ok i think maybe 2 years is not really a small amount of time as im taking it to be.. they could have had a turn of things after the first incident at shalinis home -